# c++ making coord globally accessible

Tags: c++

just a real quicky, which I feel like might be a basic question, but I just can't wrap my head around how to make it work. I've declared two coordinate points in:

```
int X = (0);
int Y = (0);
COORD coord;
coord.X = X;
coord.Y = Y;
```

They have been declared prior to main, as they need to be globally accessible to further functions within my program, but I am getting error messages when trying to set coord.X/Y, saying that the declaration has no storage type. What can I do to fix this?

Comment: So all 5 lines shown here are outside of main (or any other function)? That´s just wrong. Only the third line may be outside.

Comment: Unfortunately you used words to describe the bits of code that you _left out_.  Can you please show more context?  Is _ALL_ that code you posted appearing in the global area?  That would explain it.  Also a possibility is that `COORD` is forward-declared and not yet defined

Comment: @deviantfan Actually the first three.

Comment: @immibis Yeah right. I´m thinking slower than typing again :/

Comment: you want to add ctor to COORD and initialize as COORD coord(x,y)

Comment: @Vardhan If it´s this COORD https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682119%28v=vs.85%29.aspx, adding constructors or changing anything else is a bad idea...

Answer (score 2):

```
int X = (0);
int Y = (0);
COORD coord;
```

These are *definitions* of global variables, together with initialisation from some literal values for the first two.

```
coord.X = X;
coord.Y = Y;
```

These are *statements*.

You cannot have statements outside of any function, they need to be put into some function like e.g. `main`.

But to initialise the member fields of an instance of a class like `COORD` you normally use the constructor of that class:

```
struct COORD {
  int x;
  int y;
  COORD(int x, int y)
   : x(x), y(y) {
  }
};

COORD p = COORD (21, 42);
```

But in this case you wouldn't even need an constructor at all, you can use structure initialisation:

```
struct COORD {
  int x;
  int y;
};
COORD q = {42, 21};
COORD p{21, 42}; // universal construction
```

But, finally, I highly doubt that you really need a global variable. You should probably check your overall design. (Though all of the above is unrelated to whether you use it to initialise a global or local or member variable)